# Filtering sets of data from within another set

Tags: c#, linq, select, set

I've been reading the docs and tutorials on LINQ queries but can't seem to get it right. I have a model similar to this one and am using entity framework to persist it:

```
public class Question
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public string Question {set;get;}
  public DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
  public List<Answer> Answers {set; get;}
}

public class Answer
{
  public int Id {set; get;}
  public string UserAnswer {get;set;}
  public DateTime DateAnswered {get;set;}
  public User TheUserWhoAnswerd {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
  public int Id { get;set;}
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  public DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}
  public List<Question> Questions { get;set;}
}


The data context has something like this
public HashSet<Question> AllOfTheQuestionsDb {get;set;}
public HashSet<Answer> AllOfTheAnswersDb {get;set;}
public HashSet<User> AllOfTheUsersDb {get;set;}
```

My flow is similar to stack overflow --trivia style.

The system can assign questions to users (question are generated by the system i.e. admin , and initially don't belong to anyone). After that, the same questions can be assigned to multiple different users. each user can then answer the question.

The question holds a list of answers that were given to it.

So for instance if question 1 was assigned to users 1 through 10, but only user 2 and 4 answered, that question will only have 2 answers in the "Answers list".

My goal is to be able to do some basic sorts and selects on the data source.

For instance:

1. For a given user - UserA -, return all questions where UserA **did not** answer that question.
2. for all questions in system, return all users that the question was assigned to but that user did/didn't answer
3. selecting questions and answers for a user that were/were not answered after a given date

Comment: How to tell if a question is not answered?

Comment: Are you looking for specifically those three questions in your "For instance", or ...

Comment: I want to understand how to do a "select in a select"

Comment: select all question in user.question where questions.answers doesnt' cantain user = this.user

Comment: `.Select()` tells LINQ what type of data to return, you're probably looking for `.Where()`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested them, but I think it should give you what you want.

```
int UserA = 1;
// For a given user - UserA -, return all questions where UserA did not answer that question
// Look for questions where the count of UserA appearances is zero.
List<Question> NotAnsweredByUserA = AllOfTheQuestionsDb.Where(a => a.Answers.Count(b => b.TheUserWhoAnswerd.Id == UserA) == 0).ToList();

// For all questions in system, return all users that the question was assigned to but that user did/didn't answer
// Look for answers in questions where a User has been assigned, but no answer, and select that user
List<User> NotAnsweredButAssigned = AllOfTheQuestionsDb.SelectMany(a => a.Answers.Where(b => b.TheUserWhoAnswerd != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(b.UserAnswer)).Select(c => c.TheUserWhoAnswerd)).ToList();

// Selecting questions and answers for a user that were not answered after a given date
// Select the questions where the answer contains an answer date before today and answered by UserA
List<Question> NotAnsweredBeforeDate = AllOfTheQuestionsDb.Where(a=>a.Answers.Any(b=>b.DateAnswered < DateTime.Now && b.TheUserWhoAnswerd.Id == UserA)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close or give you a good starting point:

```
List<Question> QuestionsUnasweredByUser(User givenUser)
{
    return AllOfTheQuestionsDb
           .Where(q => q.Answers
                        .Any(a => AllOfTheAnswersDb
                                  .Where(na => na.TheUserWhoAnswerd.Id != givenUser.Id)
                                  .ToList().Contains(a)))
           .ToList();
}

List<User> UserAssignedQuestions(bool answered)
{
    return AllOfTheUsersDb
           .Where(u => u.Questions.Count > 0 && 
                       answered ? u.Questions.Any(q=> q.Answers.Count > 0) 
                                : u.Questions.Any(q=>q.Answers.Count == 0)).ToList();
}

List<Question> OverdueQuestions(User givenUser, DateTime dueDate, bool answered)
{
    return AllOfTheQuestionsDb
          .Where(q => (q.Answers.Count == 0 && !answered) || 
                       q.Answers.Any(a => a.TheUserWhoAnswerd.Id == givenUser.Id && 
                                          answered ? a.DateAnswered > dueDate  
                                              : a.DateAnswered <= dueDate)).ToList();
}

List<Answer> OverdueAnswers(User givenUser, DateTime dueDate, bool answered)
{
    return AllOfTheAnswersDb
          .Where(a => a.TheUserWhoAnswerd.Id == givenUser.Id && 
                      answered ? a.DateAnswered < dueDate 
                               : a.DateAnswered <= dueDate).ToList();
}
```